# How to make items in a Discord bot currency system usable?

Tags: discord.js, bots, currency, items

I've been recently trying to code in a Discord bot currency system using Sequelize, but the code that I wrote to make items usable for a server doesn't seem to work.
I mostly want it so that if I type in d!use  the server member can use the item.
Here's a bit of the code I've written:

```
UserItems.belongsTo(CurrencyShop, { foreignKey: 'item_id', as: 'item' });
const userItem = await UserItems.findOne({
where: { user_id: this.user_id, item_id: item.id },
});
if (!userItem) {
    return message.channel.send("You don't own this item!");
} else {
    return message.channel.send(`You used ${item}`);
    await user.removeItem(item);
}
```

Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the `removeItem()` method is correctly typed, the only problem here is that you are returning the `message.channel.send` before using the `removeItem()` method and that causes the resulting if-else statement before removing the item from the database.

Try to change if-else statement to this:

```
if (!userItem) {
    return message.channel.send("You don't own this item!");
} else {
    message.channel.send(`You used ${item}`);
    return await user.removeItem(item);
}
```